# bootstrap taginput is not making its text as tag after focus out of taginput field when using typeahead

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Tags</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control ticketData" id="task_tags" name="task_tags" value="{{$taskTags}}" data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="Add tags as Tag 1, Tag 2,">
</div>

$('#ticketDetails #task_tags').tagsinput({
     typeaheadjs: {
      name: 'tasktagnames',
      displayKey: 'value',
      valueKey: 'value',
      source: tasktagnames.ttAdapter()
     }
});
```

Comment: Hi, please add some detail; see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, when we put bootstrap tag input with typeahead or autocomplete on input field. But typed text not convert to tag-input after focus out/blur from input field.
following is a fix worked for me

`$('body').on('blur', '.tt-input', function() {
    $(this).trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', {which: 13}));
});`

Comment: Thank's man.. it's work for me.. Save my energy. stuck from 3 days.